# Why does not Intellij follow the kotlin syntax in the null safety part of type hint?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Simple example

[image: simple example]

Intellij uses `!` in NotNull type's type hint.

However, it is against the kotlin syntax. Why does Intellij ignore the syntax of kotlin that they created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `LocalDate` belongs to Java API, not to Kotlin, and `now` is not annotated with `@NotNull` or one of the other supported annotations ([here's the complete list](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations)).
Because of that, Kotlin doesn't know if the returned value might (not) be `null`, so it marks the type with `!` (as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types)).

In the second example, you "force" the type to be not-nullable (as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)), but this will cause an exception to be thrown if the real value is actually `null`.